# What is the nature of seedless fruits?

Tags: plant-physiology, mutations, fruit

Can seedless fruit be produced in nature without humans interfering with the fruit? And would that be considered a spontaneous mutation?

Comment: Is a mule "seedless fruit"? What might the difference be? Whether there's a spontaneous mutation or a hybrid that cannot reproduce doesn't matter, since the vast majority of these will not even be recognized by anyone (they can't propagate.) Furthermore, fruit can be seedless without genetic abnormalities, but based on growth conditions (granted this is very hit or miss.) Have you never found a seedless apple? (I have. I peel and cut up apples. Apples without seeds are not extremely rare.)

Comment: Questions here are expected to demonstrate prior research, like things you've read that motivate your question or show where you've gotten in trying to find an answer. It's also expected to look at existing questions here, for example searching https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=seedless

Comment: Some examples: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19093/confusion-regarding-seedless-grape-and-the-normal-process-of-germination https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16754/how-are-oranges-in-the-us-or-anywhere-made-seedless https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/80153/how-can-seedless-fruits-not-be-gmo - do any of these answer your question? If not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seedless fruits are the result of a biological process called parthenocarpy – the development of a fruit without prior fertilization. Seedless plants are not common, but they do exist naturally or can be manipulated by plant breeders without using genetic engineering techniques.

Spontaneous mutations are naturally occurring alterations in the DNA due to slippage in natural processes. Also, as said before, The seedless plants are rare but can occur naturally ,i.e., without any human interference. So, yes it can be considered as spontaneous mutation.

If you cross a horse and a donkey, you get a mule. Mules can't reproduce — they are, in essence, "seedless".

**Source:** [Seedless fruit is not something new](https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/seedless-fruit-is-not-something-new)